# HttpListener Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, service, httplistener

I have to establish an `HttpListener` that will wait for requests made by our client's server. I have to receive that request on port 8088 and extract the query string. That is the easy part.

I'm running the `HttpListener` in a windows service. I cannot get it to fire properly. I build the setup project install the service on our server and it never starts. I suspect there's an error with my code.

HttpListenerClass:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace lalalolo
{
    class HttpListenerClass
    {
        bool keepAlive = true;

        public void AddToFile(string contents)
        {
            var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\HttpListenerserv.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            var sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            sw.WriteLine(contents);
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
        }

        private HttpListener listener;

        public HttpListenerClass()
        {
            ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(50, 100);
            ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(50, 50);
            listener = new HttpListener();
            listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8088/");
        }

        public void Start()
        {

            listener.Start();
            if(keepalive == true){
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpListenerContext ctx = listener.GetContext();
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ProcessRequest), ctx);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    AddToFile(ex.Message);
                }
              }
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            listener.Stop();
            keepalive == false;
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(object listenerContext)
        {
            try
            {
                var context = (HttpListenerContext)listenerContext;
                string QS = context.Request.QueryString["ID"];
                AddToFile(QS);
            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                AddToFile(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Service1.cs:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace lalalolo
{
    public partial class HttpListenerTest1 : ServiceBase
    {
        HttpListenerClass HTTP = new HttpListenerClass();

        public void AddToFile(string contents)
        {
            var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\HttpListenerserv.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            var sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            sw.WriteLine(contents);
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
        }

        public HttpListenerTest1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            HTTP.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            HTTP.Stop();   
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Look at the event log and post the error you see in there here.

Comment: When you say "it never starts" can you be more specific?  How are you trying to start it?  Does it fail with an error?  Is that error visible on the console, or in the event viewer?  Maybe wrap the whole thing in a try/catch and write any exception somewhere to see if that sheds some light on the problem?

Comment: It will be awfully exciting to see what happens when two threads enter the `AddToFile()` method at the same time. ;)

Comment: @Dragan: I've taken this code and modified it for my own use. May I have permission to license it as MIT / Apache2 with reference to this SO post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queuing worker items in a `while(true)` loop? Are you serious?!

1. Your `OnStart` method never returns because of that `while` loop. However, returning from the `OnStart` method is essential for the service manager to know, that your service started correctly.
2. Your service will probably just die with an `OutOfMemoryException` or something similar, because of that endless loop.

**Suggestion:**
Try adopting [this sample](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/simple_http_server.shtml). It is in IronPython but that also uses the .NET framework. Hint: The `while(true)` in that implementation should be changed to be able to break the while loop when your service is being stopped. Additionally, you must call `serveforever` in your `Start` method in an async way.
This should get you going.

Comment: Hmmm...yeah, what's up with that?

Comment: Daniel, I borrow that part of the code from an answered question on the internet you see. What would you say I must change in the code? Thank you so much guys for your feedback!!

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth - Pretty harsh.  He is trying to learn.  He tried to copy code and it isn't working.  Then he came here and is asking about fixing it.  I don't think of this as a forum to make judgment calls about people's job worth...

Comment: I know it's harsh and I would feel sorry for him, if he would *really* lose his job. But (1) I don't think he is getting fired if he can't solve this and (2) there are enough good tutorials out there that explain stuff, so you can do it properly. Obviously, he is just too lazy to invest that time. Bottom line: I don't like the way he works, and that's what I am saying.

Comment: oh my god.. Only now did I realise what I have done. So I declare a boolean variable keepAlive = true;. Can I try this in the Start method of HttpListenerClass -> if(keepalive == true){...} and then change the keepalive value in the Stop() method? That should do the job I reckon.

Comment: @skaz - I'd be right with you, if this person was not suggesting his entire career hangs on his wide-ranging lack of prowess here. If he were a hobbyist looking to do this same thing with the same knowledge-base, this would be understandable. But...

Comment: I've tried EVERY single tutorial on HttpListener on the NET. The one that MSDN offers is just useless. I've implemented Windows Services far more complex that this one. This is my first encounter with the HttpListener class. I've tried async handling as well as the regular listener.getContext(). Rly nothing seemed to work. As far as my career is concerned. I'm on a test period in a decent IT company. I graduated 2 months ago. This is the first time i'm actually facing real life problems and not just reading about the in books. Thanks for your constructive criticism!

Comment: If you have created multiple, "complex" Windows services not knowing any more than you do how to implement the `ServiceBase.Start()` method, well; that's exactly why I'm done with this question!

Comment: +1 Good answer, btw. That little 'logging' function might be the next source of job-woes, once the Listener/Service stuff is sorted!

Comment: @Andrew: I hope he learns that he needs to really understand how stuff is working...

Comment: @Dan Puzey: Provide a better one and read all comments. The answer has no error in it and tries to help the OP. So no reason for a downvote here! Do you expect me to fix his code or what is the reasoning behind your downvote?

Comment: @Dan Puzey: The edit happend 16 minutes before your comment. I am quite confused, right now ;-)

Comment: Okay so final solution to my problem. Right after I call listener.Start() in the Start method of HttpListenerClass i should first call a new thread that will run an endless loop and there I call the listener.GetContext() method. The reason for this is because listener.GetContext() blocks until it gets a request. Agreed that this is the final solution? Daniel I appreciate your constructiveness! Cheers

Comment: @Dragan: Without further investigating it, this sounds like a reasonable way to do it. Things to check: (1) `OnStart` returns right away and doesn't contain any blocking code (2) Your endless loop will stop, when the service is stopped.

Comment: @Daniel: how can I upvote you and mark you reply as answer! I wish there were more ppl like you around!

Comment: @Dragan: You can't upvote, because you have less than 15 reputation. How to accept my answer is explained in the link in my last comment...

Comment: I can't help but comment on this even though it's very old.  After years of using stackoverflow I was bummed at Daniel's response.  The community in general seems so positive and helpful.  I was stunned at how harse Daniel was to the guy asking the question.  Thank God not everyone is like him on the site otherwise it would be unusable.

Comment: @ryan1234: You are right, the tone on this answer wasn't right. However, have a look at my other answers and how many of them there are. Everyone has a bad day once in a while... Still, the answer and my follow up comments helped the OP, that's why I haven't deleted it long ago.

Comment: Makes sense.  Lord knows I've had my days where I've lost it on someone.  Thanks for the reply.  =)  Restoring my faith.